# сортировка через get

Tags: php, javascript, get

Есть таблица с пагинацией, которая работает параметром get значение которого подставляется в ссылки ( снизу на картинке )

[image: таблица и ссылки пагинации]

Как сделать сортировку(гет запросом)по полям, из шапки таблицы, с земеной ask desc при двойном нажатии (с js совсем все печально , но если ни как средствами 
 php ,постараюсь понять)

Проблемы которые возникают при такой же реализации(как в пагинации):
2 одинаковых гет параметра по типу (&sortBy=id&sortBy=id&...)при неоднократном нажатии

смена  ? и & по ситуации ,если добавлять к url &sortBy=id может получиться так :
localhost/index.php&.....

PS
нагуглил, что можно убрать все строки из таблицы отформатировать jsом и вернуть в таблицу подскажите как по проще это реализовать? Если без js не обойтись

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы сделать сортировку передавайте параметры сортировки в свой скрипт. В php есть отличная функция `http_build_query`. Воспользуйтесь ей:

```
index.php?<?= http_build_query(['sortBy' => 'id', 'sortDirection' => 'asc']) ?>
```

В таком случае get-параметры у вас будут ровно те, что вы укажите. И проблем с ? и & не будет.

Правильные наборы параметров сформировать довольно просто:

```
<?php

function makeSortLinks($columns, $currentQuery) {
    $currentSortBy = $currentQuery['sortBy']?? '';
    $currentSortDirection = $currentQuery['sortDirection']?? '';

    $links = [];
    foreach ($columns as $column) {
        if ($currentSortBy === $column) {
            $sortDirection = ($currentSortDirection === 'desc')? 'asc' : 'desc';
        } else {
            $sortDirection = 'asc';
        }
        $links[$column] = http_build_query([
            'sortBy' => $column,
            'sortDirection' => $sortDirection,
        ]);
    }

    return $links;
}

$links = makeSortLinks(['id', 'userName', 'email'],  $_GET);
var_dump($links);
```

Затем просто используете этот набор:

```
<a href="/index.php?<?= $links['id'] ?>">id</a>
```

С пагинацией поступайте так же:

```
index.php?<?= http_build_query(['page' => $page] + $_GET) ?>
```

Comment: немного понял ( правильный url можно и в ручную нарисовать в логике), а как передавать параметры  с страницы и переходя по пагинационным ссылкам не терять эти параметры?

Comment: @АлександрЖарков Если в массиве параметров, менять только нужный, то всё будет работать как надо. Я специально добавил пример с пагинацией. Объединение массивов приводит к тому что все значения из $_GET сохраняются, а page добавляется или перезаписывается. В параметры ссылок сортировки добавлять page не стал, так как обычно нет смысла оставаться на текущей странице, если записи теперь следуют в другом порядке (но при желании можно сохранить страницу, если так удобно пользователям).

Comment: Блин ,чтот я совсем тугой походу. Получается я делаю все это чтобы в GET передавать параметры которые я обрабатываю на логике и фильтрую выходные данные , но чтобы мне сделать гет мне опять же нужны параметры ( которые я не передал) , замкнутый круг вроде получается "чтобы работать мне нужно есть, а чтобы есть мне нужно работать"

Comment: а еще, спасибо огромное . Чучуть понял, сейчас еще пару тысяч раз перечитаю и разберусь.

Comment: @АлександрЖарков круг помогают разомкнуть значения по умолчанию :-) Пустой  $_GET тоже будет работать. 1) Параметров нет -- в ссылке пагинации окажется только page. 2) Нажали на сортировку, в параметрах оказались sortBy и sortDirection, теперь в пагинации они тоже есть!